# Laravel request always return null

Tags: php, laravel

So i have this view

```
<form method="POST" action="/store">
<div class="control-group after-add-more">  
<div class="form-group">                                                                    
<label>Partner :</label>                                                                        
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="partner" name="partner" value="" placeholder="Partner Name" />                                                                  
</div>                                                          
<button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button">                                                         
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Plus Partner</button>                                                      
                                            
<div class="copy hide">                                                         
<div class="control-group">                                                                     
<div class="form-group">                                                                        
<label> Partner :</label>                                                                       
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="partner2" name="partner2" value="" placeholder="Partner Name" />                                                                    
</div>                                                                                                                              
<button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button">                                                                    
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>                                                          
Delete Partner</button>
</div>      
                                            
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

this is jquery that i use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $(".add-more").click(function() {
            var html = $(".copy").html();
            $(".after-add-more").after(html);
        });
        $("body").on("click", ".remove",function() {
            $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
        });
});
```

but when i try to submit , the input partner2 is returning null value

this is my controller

```
$kerma = Kerma::find(1)->get();
$kerma->partner()->createMany(['partner' => $request->input('partner')],['partner' => $request->input('partner2')])
```

anyone have a solution for me ?  thanks in advance

Comment: Try `var_dump($request->input('partner2'));` without the `return` phrase

Comment: same the result is still null

Comment: Please paste the whole code of your HTML file and controller file

Comment: https://www116.zippyshare.com/v/nyHkmxvF/file.html here sir

Comment: Please paste it to your question. So, someone can help you with that :)

Answer (score 1):

When submitting your request to the form:

1. The routes file should have the `POST` method configured.

```php
Route::post('store', 'YourController@yourmethod');
```

2. Addition of CSRF token to the Form to prevent `Page Expired` issue. So, your blade file should be like below:

```php
<form method="POST" action="{{url('store')}}">
@csrf
<div class="control-group after-add-more">  
<div class="form-group">                                                                    
<label>Partner :</label>                                                                        
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="partner" name="partner" value="" placeholder="Partner Name" />                                                                  
</div>                                                          
<button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button">                                                         
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Plus Partner</button>                                                      
                                            
<div class="copy hide">                                                         
<div class="control-group">                                                                     
<div class="form-group">                                                                        
<label> Partner :</label>                                                                       
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="partner2" name="partner2" value="" placeholder="Partner Name" />                                                                    
</div>                                                                                                                              
<button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button">                                                                    
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>                                                          
Delete Partner</button>
</div>      
                                            
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it still returing null to partner2

Comment: i think the problem at jquery

Comment: when i decided to not use jquery , the partner2 is returning correct value